# How to define flatmap for state monad-like thing

Tags: python, monads, state-monad

I'm trying to work out how to define `flatmap` for my state monad-like thing.

```
class State(Protocol[T_co]):
    @abstractmethod
    def __call__(self: S, i: int) -> tuple[T_co, S]:
        ...
```

A `State` encapsulates the state. Here's `unit`

```
def unit(t: T) -> State[T]:
    return lambda _: (t, unit(t))
```

I got the design from a book where they use `State[S, A] = S -> (A, S)` but I found that a bit cumbersome (and also needed the extra argument `i`), so here a `class Foo(State[int])` is almost like a `State[Foo, int]`. I wonder if my attempt to simplify it has stopped it being a monad.

I tried something like

```
def flatmap(f: Callable[[T], State[U]], s: State[T]) -> State[U]:
    def stateful(i: int) -> tuple[U, State[U]]:
        t, s_new = s(i)
        u, su = f(t)(i)
        return u, flatmap(f, s_new)  # or u, su

    return stateful
```

but though I think this satisfies identity (haven't checked associativity), I'd expect to use both new states `s_new` and `su`.

For the sake of completeness, here's a horror which is a literal translation of `flatmap` from the book which uses `S -> (A, S)` to my case, with an extra argument `i: int`. I have zero expectations it will work

```
def flatmap(f: Callable[[T], State[U]], s: State[T]) -> State[U]:
    class _State(State[U]):
        def __call__(self, i: int) -> tuple[U, _State]:
            x, y = type(s).__call__(self, i)
            return type(f(x)).__call__(y, i)

    return _State()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't possible. The standard definition of state uses a `S -> (A, S)`. Adding an extra argument `(S, int) -> (A, S)` may or may not break it, but what probably will is the fact that a `(S, int) -> (A, S)` can accept anything as it first argument, whereas an instance of (a subclass of) `class State` can only accept an instance of that class as `self`. That is, I've restricted myself to a `State` that can only accept itself as a first argument. How exactly this precludes defining a `flatmap` I'm still trying to work out.